# facebook graph API with objective c

Tags: objective-c, facebook, facebook-graph-api

How can I get a name using the facebook id using facebook graph API?
I used this code to get the image data from id:

```
UIImage* new_image=[UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://graph.facebook.com/id/picture?type=normal"]]];
NSData *imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(new_image);
```

how would I do something like this but for the User's name?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make the `\GET` request to:

> http://graph.facebook.com/{user-id}?fields=username

You'll get the response as-

```
{
  username: "XXXXX",
  id: "9999999"
}
```

[Example](http://graph.facebook.com/595273610?fields=username)